# Exam class: Each question on new page

Tags: environments, page-breaking, exam

I have an exam class document containing only questions (about 500 or so questions) using

```
\begin{questions}
\question[5] Question 1 text
\question[10] Question 2 txt
\question[10] Question 3 txt
...
\question[10] Question 500 txt
\end{questions}
```

I don't intend to generate solutions for any question. Currently all questions appear one after the other in the document.

Now I want each question to appear on a new page. What is the easiest/fastest way to do this without adding solutions environment to each question manually?

I did NOT add the following code after each \question environment to leave all the remaining space on the page blank (as advised in the manual).

```
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\newpage
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Is there a way to modify:

```
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{1in}}
```

As given in the exam class manual, this command inserts additional one inch of blank space between questions.

Comment: Why not just `\newpage` without the `vspace*` ?

Comment: Even then, that would require to add `/newpage` after each question. The solution demands for simple command to get new question on each page.

Comment: @DilpreetKaur: Strictly speaking, adding `\newpage` before each question, as suggested by Peter Wilson, would be an easy search-and-replace job for a text editor, so it *does* count as a solution in my eyes. – Still, your desired approach would be much cleaner. Have you tried sth like `\newcommand{\pagequestion}{\newpage\question}` and `\pagequestion[10]`? It works for me.

Comment: Thanks but I don't wish to use the editor find-replace-all. I would like a latex based solution. Your given command does not work.

Comment: For the sake of accuracy and for reference: That command does work (with the desired output) in a properly constructed, *minimal* document (`\documentclass{exam}`) I made for testing purposes. You didn't give us a MWE to work with: that's all I could do. – To the point: I agree with your requiring a clean solution (setting one parameter > find-replace-all). It's surprisingly difficult, though.`\question` resists to many of the direct approaches (renewcommand, patch, appto, \let\oldquestion\question etc.). It might be worth contacting the [maintainer](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) about this.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution involves defining a new command `\pagequestion` that places a page break *immediately before* a `\question`. (1) OP was looking to insert a page break *after* the question not *before*. Arguably, this has the same effect ("I want each question to appear on a new page").

(2) I couldn't find a way to `\let` LaTeX process `\question` as `\pagequestion` though. Thus, the present solution  requires using `\pagequestion` *instead of* `\question` (or *substituting* it via search-and-replace). More proficient users may suggest a way to do this.

For reason (2), my solution is messier than the one envisioned by OP. *It doesn't meet their explicitly stated criteria, unfortunately.* However, as it might be still useful for others encountering the same problem, here's an answer **for future reference**, with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\newcommand{\pagequestion}{\newpage\question}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\pagequestion[5] Question 1 text
\pagequestion[10] Question 2 txt
\pagequestion[10] Question 3 txt
...
\pagequestion[10] Question 500 txt
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: each question on a new page]